# Как сделать ajax фильтр по наличию товаров в woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать чекбокс для клиентов сайта для фильтрации товаров по наличию?

То есть сделать аналог вот этой настройки в woocommerce[image: натройка видимости в woocommerce]

только для клиентов сайта. И нужно чтобы фильтр работал на ajax.

Comment: Покажите что вы уже сделали

Comment: @Krya как бы ничего наверное) пробовал плагин WooCommerce Extra Product Sorting Options он дает не фильтрацию, а сортировку, вот в коде его  пытаюсь разобраться. А чтобы просто отфильтровать из запроса, те товары, которые  "В наличии" я делал вот так:

`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_product_category()) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
        $query->set('meta_value', 'instock');
    }
}`

А как создать для этого чекбокс и соединить, разбираюсь...

Comment: 1. Создай метаполе. 2. Сохрани метаполе. 3. Отправь AJAX и верни нужную разметку

Comment: @Krya спасибо, буду пробовать